# How to reuse the function of a controller class in playFramework

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

Say I have two functions in a Controller class :

```
public class Application extends Controller {

   public static Result method1() {

     String results;
     //step1
     //step2
     //step3
     ...
     return ok(results);

   }

   public static Result method2() {

     String results;
     //step1
     //step2
     //step3
     //step4
     return ok(results);

   }


}
```

In both methods steps from 1 to 3 are exactly identical in both functions
is there anyway of using `method1()` in `method2()` i.e. calling `method1()` in `method2()`?

**NOTE:**
I know I can make a method that does step 1 to 3 and use that method in both controller's method, but I don't want to do that as it creates further complexity.

Comment: I would argue that "calliing `method1` from `method2`" will create far more complexity for you, considering their return value, than you making a private method with steps 1 to 3. Because instead of reusable method with sane return values you'd have to parse `Result` inside `method2` to first extract those same values and only then doing step 4 (and what if there's an exception in method1 or some other `Result` besides `ok()`?).

Comment: @M.Prokhorov you are probably right, the fact is I don't  know how complicated it would be to do this. however if we use playframework as a service api which only returns <json>  then this approach could potentially reduce the complexity dramatically